# If Else statement does not recognize my comboBox

Tags: c#

I am having an issue with my if else statements. When I submit the information, it should read the text in the combobox and give it a defining number. However, it dropped straight to the else and inputs that. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
try
        {
            string combo;
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Random Pool")
            {
                combo = "10";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Other")
            {
                combo = "20";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "DOT Pool")
            {
                combo = "30";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Follow up")
            {
                combo = "40";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Pre-employement Screening")
            {
                combo = "50";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Aberrant Behavior")
            {
                combo = "60";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Incident/Near Miss Investigation")
            {
                combo = "70";
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Investigation")
            {
                combo = "80";
            }
            else
            {
                combo = "20";
            }
            string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO Test (SELECTION_DATE, TEST_REASON_CODE, PEOPLESOFT_EMPL_ID, TEST_TYPE_CODE) VALUES(@date, '" + combo + "', @emp, 10);";
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE of some sort? Please run this in debug mode and see what the value of `comboBox1.SelectedText` is when you get to this code.

Comment: I don't know how to run it in debug mode. I'm pretty new to C#. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: above code written in selected changed event or any button click event

Comment: You add a breakpoint by clicking to the left of the line where you want to stop and press the play button on the top bar to begin debugging. Hover over variables to see their values.

Comment: @user3538446 try to run our code in debug mode by pressing F11 or F10 and check how your code is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that in your code, it is checking `if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Investigation")`, and if it's not, it sets *combo* to `"20"`. Either write if, else if, else if, etc.. Even if any of the previous if conditions have been executed, the one at the bottom always wins, you can do something as shown below:

```
        string combo;
        if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Random Pool")
        {
            combo = "10";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Other")
        {
            combo = "20";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "DOT Pool")
        {
            combo = "30";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Follow up")
        {
            combo = "40";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Pre-employement Screening")
        {
            combo = "50";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Aberrant Behavior")
        {
            combo = "60";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Incident/Near Miss Investigation")
        {
            combo = "70";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Investigation")
        {
            combo = "80";
        }
        else
        {
            combo = "20";
        }
```

Or, you could simply create a function:

```
string GetCombo()
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Random Pool")
        return "10";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Other")
        return "20";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "DOT Pool")
        return "30";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Follow up")
        return "40";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Pre-employement Screening")
        return "50";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Aberrant Behavior")
        return "60";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Incident/Near Miss Investigation")
        return "70";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Investigation")
        return "80";
    return "20";
}
```

and in your code,

```
string combo = GetCombo();
string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO Test (SELECTION_DATE, TEST_REASON_CODE, PEOPLESOFT_EMPL_ID, TEST_TYPE_CODE) VALUES(@date, '" + combo + "', @emp, 10);";
// ...
```

Hope it helps! :)

Edit: As mentioned by Asad, you could use a switch statement, like this:

```
string GetCombo()
{
    switch(comboBox1.SelectedText)
    {
        case "Random Pool":
            return "10";
        case "Other":
            return "20";
        case "DOT Pool":
            return "30";
        case "Follow up":
            return "40";
        case "Pre-employement Screening":
            return "50";
        case "Aberrant Behavior":
            return "60";
        case "Incident/Near Miss Investigation":
            return "70";
        case "Investigation":
            return "80";
        default:
            return "20";
    }
```

}

Comment: Good catch. Ideally this would be a switch statement however. `switch(comboBox1.SelectedText) { case "Random Pool": combo = "10"; break; ... default: combo = "20"; break; }`

Comment: @Asad, you're right. Did not think of that, will write another code with a switch statement! Thanks :)

Comment: Anytime, happy to hear that! Good luck :)

Comment: You don't need to copy the value into a local in the switch snippet, that happens internally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

Change `Text` instead of `Selected Text`

```
try
        {
            string combo;
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Random Pool")
            {
                combo = "10";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Other")
            {
                combo = "20";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "DOT Pool")
            {
                combo = "30";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Follow up")
            {
                combo = "40";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Pre-employement Screening")
            {
                combo = "50";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Aberrant Behavior")
            {
                combo = "60";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Incident/Near Miss Investigation")
            {
                combo = "70";
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text== "Investigation")
            {
                combo = "80";
            }
            else
            {
                combo = "20";
            }
            string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO Test (SELECTION_DATE, TEST_REASON_CODE, PEOPLESOFT_EMPL_ID, TEST_TYPE_CODE) VALUES(@date, '" + combo + "', @emp, 10);";
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
        }
```